# jQuery: How to hover a child of child element when hovering on the main element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover

I have this  code:

```
$('.icon-click').mouseenter(function () {
  console.log('banana');
   $(this).hover(function(){
     $(this).children("img");
   });
});
```

```html
<div class="circles-cont">
  <div class="col-sm-4 text-center icon-click">
    <p class="circle">
      <img class="search" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/w/N/I/K/O/9/smaller-red-button-th.png">
    </p>
    <p class="thetext">
      <span>Search</span>
      <br/>
      <span>afasfasfa</span>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4 text-center icon-click">
    <p class="circle ">
      <img class="conv" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/w/N/I/K/O/9/smaller-red-button-th.png">
    </p>
    <p class="thetext">
      <span>asfsfas</span>
      <br/>
      <span>asfasfasf</span>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4 text-center icon-click">
    <p class="circle ">
      <img class="local" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/w/N/I/K/O/9/smaller-red-button-th.png">
    </p>
    <p class="thetext">
      <span>asfasasf</span>
    </p>
  </div>
```

I am trying to get the result of the img:hover for each element sepretly only when hovering on it's main `.icon-click` element.

https://jsfiddle.net/0rwe5z23/2/

Comment: I really have no idea what you want to do ...

Comment: Do you mean this? https://jsfiddle.net/0rwe5z23/5/

Comment: Glad it worked @RickSanchez. I made it an answer then. I even add a version without js, maybe that works four you too. Then it would even work with disabled js. Mark it as success if you like to ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `hover` to take effect of the `:hover` selecter on css classes. But you can create a class with your changes and redirect this by jQuery's `$.hover` function to the elements you want.

```
$(".icon-click").hover(function() {
    $(this).find("img").addClass("hovered");
}, function() {
    $(this).find("img").removeClass("hovered");
});
```

[Working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/0rwe5z23/5/)

But you can even do the whole thing without js. Just use the `:hover` on the parent. Like this:

```
.icon-click:hover img {
    background-color: black;
}
```

[Working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/0rwe5z23/6/)